# What should the "source" in the podspec be for a privately hosted react-native library?

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I am developing a private react-native library for ios. 
The code is hosted on private git repo and accessible only to a few people. 
The podspec file I have currently is something like this:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "SomeName"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "SomeSummary"
  s.description  = <<-DESC
                  SomeDescription
                   DESC
  s.homepage     = "https://somehomepage.com"
  s.platform     = :ios, "9.0"
  s.source_files  = "*.{h,m}"
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.author       = "someAuthor"
  s.dependency "React"
end
```

The problem that I am having is that when I use the library on a local react-native app and do pod install, i get an error:

```
The `SomeName` pod failed to validate due to 1 error:
    - WARN  | attributes: Missing required attribute `license`.
    - ERROR | attributes: Missing required attribute `source`.
    - WARN  | license: Missing license type.
    - WARN  | description: The description is equal to the summary.
```

What should the `source` be in this case?

Answer (score 2):

`source` should specify the private github repo. See docs and examples [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#source).